# Not geting any checked value from the radio buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.Data.Gender, "Male" , item.Data.Gender == "Male" ? new { id="rdoMale", Checked = "checked" } : null)  Male

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.Data.Gender, "Female" , item.Data.Gender == "Female" ? new { id="rdoFemale", Checked = "checked" } : null)  Female
```

How could i get the text "Male" when Male radio button is checked or "Female" when female radio button is checked.

I am trying with jquery to get this .Please help me

Comment: If you're trying with jQuery, why did you post the serverside ASP code ?

Comment: Post jQuery that you're trying!

Comment: wire up a onclick of radio button and get the value by $(this).val()

Comment: while using the <input type= "radio"> i am getting what i need , the problem i am not getting .val() , .text() , :checked).val() anything using jquery

Answer (score 0):

add a class on both:

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.Data.Gender, "Male" , item.Data.Gender == "Male" ? new { id="rdoMale", Checked = "checked",class="CheckBoxes" } : null)  Male

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.Data.Gender, "Female" , item.Data.Gender == "Female" ? new { id="rdoFemale", Checked = "checked",class="c" } : null)  Female
```

Jquery:

```
$(".CheckBoxes").on('click',function(){

alert($(this).val());

})
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAeY7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are making a Radio button then it will store a name with it.
That name can be `Male` or `Female`.

So when you select any one of them then you have to use its Name, 
As I have used [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aJ4X4/1/)

Comment: use the name property in the fiddle so that one of them is clicked . Rest is good I think....